# Want to Extract fb_dtsg variable from facebook using cURL

Tags: php, curl

There is a hidden variable named "fb_dtsg" if we open any Fan Page in Facebook.

How do i extract the value of it using PHP(cURL)?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried about curl and PHP? Where is it failing? BTW, I would recommend you use APIs for what you are looking at..

Comment: preg_match("/input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fb_dtsg\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $abc, $fb_dtsg);

Comment: I am a bit confused about $abc part

Comment: $ch = curl_init ("http://www.facebook.com/nike"); $abc = curl_exec ($ch);

Comment: You are searching for an HTML in a reponse which is like the above? Do one thing, update your question with only **relevant** details(remove unnecessary headers and put your question as "I want to extract XYZ from ABC" .. Only precise questions like that can help .. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with this:

```
var fb_dtsg = document.getElementsByName('fb_dtsg')[0].value;
```

Note that i'm doing it via JavaScript because it's a javascript object,
you can't just search for the value in a string with cURL

Source: was analysing some malware and looked up the value.
if you're interested,
http://pastebin.com/0JXCVxXg

Comment: Things have changed a lot in the past 4 years. This is not part of a public fb api thus when things like these come to break it surprises no one.